# CSS wordwrapping and overflow not breaking paragraph

Tags: css

I have a paragraph next to a heading. Both are `display:inline-block` but when the page is compressed through a resolution reduction then the entire paragraph falls to the next line. I have tried `wordwrapping` and `overflow` but they seem to have no affect. Is there something else I can use ? Code below does not reflect the `wordwrapping` or `overflow`.
[image]

```css
.header_class_name {
  display: inline-block
}

.para_class_name {
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<h4 class="header_class_name">my title here</h4>
<p class="para_class_name">paragraph here</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display: inline;` inside of `display: inline-block;`.

```css
.header_class_name {
    display: inline;
}

.para_class_name { 
    display: inline; 
    word-break: break-word; 
}
```

```html
<h4 class="header_class_name">my title here</h4>
<p class="para_class_name">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

***edit*** - adding a solution based on your comment

try using `white-space: nowrap;`, if that doesn't work, you can try setting the containing div size to a higher `width`.

---

you can try doing several things:

1. wrap both divs with `<nobr>`
2. make the parent div a `flexbox` with
   `flex-direction: row; flex-wrap: nowrap;` 
   the problem with this solution is that they would 'leak' outside your viewport width, so I would consider allowing line break/making the font smaller/using `elipsis`

Comment: Since its wordpress, I am trying not to edit the main HTML but I can if need be. What about this makes it where the above CSS doesnt affect the <p>? I am not wanting to do the```elipsis``` since I want to see it all. I just dont want to have the initial paragraph down on the next line

Comment: You should write in the body of the post that it is in Wordpress :)

Comment: trouble is if you do then everyone ignores it because they dont like dealing with wordpress or people just state they know nothing about wordpress even if the question, like this one, has nothing to do with wordpress. I appreciate you taking the time to try and anwser however it did not work and I dont think in this case that was wordpress. The accepted answer was the one that did. Frankly I am not sure why it was an issue I was experiencing to start with

Answer (score 0):

You can use min-width property, so when window shrinks, layout should stay firm.

Comment: Thanks. Tried this but doesnt make a difference. It will wrap the next lines of the paragraph but not the initial line. I am not sure I understand why

Comment: [thirtythreeboas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7927629/thirtythreeboas) Could you add a snippet to show how this solution works?